# How to call a set-up method before certain JUnit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, gson, junit4

I am creating unit tests with JUnit for methods that manipulate JSON objects. I want to create a method in my test file that sets up the object that will be used in some, but not all, of my test methods. How do I selectively run the set-up method and transfer it's resulting JSONObject to the test methods? Is there a better way to do this?
Here is what I was thinking for a set up method (using gson):

```
    public static JsonObject prepareTestJson(){
        JsonObject testJson_container = new JsonObject();
        JsonObject testJson_inner = new JsonObject();
        String ContactInfo = "+1 111 111 1111";
        testJson_inner.addProperty("Contact", ContactInfo);
        testJson_container.add("ID", testJson_inner);
        return testJson_container;
    }
```

Comment: You could maybe just make a different test class. That might make more logical sense in your case. You could also just make a non-test-case method and call it each time needed. There's maybe also a JUnit way of doing this, similarly to [Boost Test's suites](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/fixtures/per_test_suite_fixture.html) in C++, but I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: Why not simply calling that method from the test they need it? Another possibility is to move test needing this preparation into a separate Test class where the preparation is done in a plain `@Before` method. *(Yes it is legal to have more than one TestClass per tested unit...)*

Answer (score 3):

> How do I selectively run the set-up method and transfer it's
>   resulting JSONObject to the test methods?

No you cannot select the test methods for which a method annotated with `@Before` should be applied.

> Is there a better way to do this?

You could simply invoke this method before each test (you can also make it `private` and an instance method to reduce its access :

```
private JsonObject prepareTestJson(){
    JsonObject testJson_container = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject testJson_inner = new JsonObject();
    String ContactInfo = "+1 111 111 1111";
    testJson_inner.addProperty("Contact", ContactInfo);
    testJson_container.add("ID", testJson_inner);
    return testJson_container;
}
```

such as :

```
@Test
public void foo(){
  JsonObject json = prepareTestJson();
  ...
}
```

Another alternative is splitting your test class in two : one with the tests that require the `setup()`  and another one with the tests that don't require it.
In this way you could use a init method with `@Before` or simply put these statements in the class constructor.
For example :

```
private JsonObject testJson_container;

@Before
public void prepareTestJson(){
    testJson_container = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject testJson_inner = new JsonObject();
    String ContactInfo = "+1 111 111 1111";
    testJson_inner.addProperty("Contact", ContactInfo);
    testJson_container.add("ID", testJson_inner);       
}
```

But this way is an artificial/technical split, it may make the test code less readable.
So I think that in most of cases, I would stick to the first way.

---

Additionally, with JUnit 5 you have an interesting workaround : using 
`@MethodSource` that is documented as :

> an ArgumentsSource which provides access to values returned by methods
>   of the class in which this annotation is declared.

This is designed to be used with `@ParameterizedTest` but it may fit to your case.

You could write :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;    

public class FooTest {

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("prepareTestJson")
  void add(JsonObject testJson_container) {
    // do your logic
  }

  private static Arguments prepareTestJson() {
     JsonObject testJson_container = new JsonObject();
     JsonObject testJson_inner = new JsonObject();
     String ContactInfo = "+1 111 111 1111";
     testJson_inner.addProperty("Contact", ContactInfo);
     testJson_container.add("ID", testJson_inner);
     return Arguments.of(testJson_container);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where would I put the private prepareTestJson() method then? I get this error when I include it in the JUnit test class `java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching Method prepareTestJson()`